# How to edit multiple record at once

Tags: symfony

I would like to know if someone knows how to be abble to **edit** multiple records through one form. This link displays the exact thing I am looking for: https://editor.datatables.net/examples/simple/multiRow.html. I already created an ajax call that sends the ids of the records I selected to a `editMultipleRecordsAction` method I created. From there I am lost. Any hint would be much appreciated (Does Symfony already have something for this? Should I rebuild a new FormType specifically for this? Should I use the same FormType but add Listeners? Should I create a new entity where my id attribute would be an array?...). By the way I only have one entity.

Comment: Ignore the rather silly answer below and just use a form collection: http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html

Comment: Perhaps you could add a few more details to your question?  So you have one entity resulting in multiple records?  Seems a bit strange.  Your multi row link sure makes it look like you have multiple entities of the same type on one form.

Comment: @Mark: You can see how I solve the problem here: "Symfony 2.8: Creating and processing a form for multiple records from the same entity" in spanish language, link: https://symfonyandme.com/2017/10/13/symfony-2-8-como-crear-y-procesar-un-formulario-para-multiples-registros-de-una-misma-entidad/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to achieve this would be:

- Iterate over `$request->request->get('data');`
- Fetch the current entity from DB
- Create a new form for current entity
- Manually call [`Form::submit()`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/direct_submit.html) for each form
- `$form->isValid()` to validate (each iteration)
- `$em->flush()` after the loop to have doctrine calculate the change set and save to database

Here is an untested example

```
public function editMultipleRecordsAction (Request $request)
{
    // First we select what to do based on 'action' field (add/edit/delete)
    switch ($request->request->get('action')) {
        case 'edit':

            // Fetch the payload
            $data = $request->request->get('data');

            // Fetch all edited entities
            $entities = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Entity')
                ->findBy(['id' => array_keys($data)]);

            // Build a map of $id => $entity to use later
            $map = [];
            foreach ($entities as $entity) {
                $map[$entity->getId()] = $entity;
            }

            if (array_keys($data) !== array_keys($map)) {
                // Something went wrong, not all requested entities were fetched
            }

            // Loop over each edited entity
            foreach ($data as $id => $form_data) {
                // Create a form for the current entity (you can use createForm() as well, same thing)
                $form = $this->createFormBuilder($map[$id])
                    // Notice that the id field is not part of the form
                    ->add('name')
                    ->add('position')
                    // ->add(...)
                    ->getForm();

                // Manually submit the data for this form
                $form->submit($form_data);

                if (!$form->isValid()) {
                    // Validation error, do something...
                }
            }

            // Now we have iterated over each entity and updated it using Symfony's Form component
            // The only thing remaining is to tell Doctrine to calculate the change set and save it to the database
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

            // DataTables require that you return a JSON version of updated entities
            // This will be different depending on what you use to serialize.
            // The following example applies if you are using FOS Rest Bundle:
            return $this->handleView($this->view(['data' => $entities]));
        break;

        case 'create':
            // ...
        break;

        case 'remove':
            // ...
        break;

        default:
            throw new BadRequestHttpException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello :) But where do I "store" my multiple ids in the form ?

Comment: @Marc You don't need ID as a field in the form. From the docs you linked I understand that DataTables put row ID as the **key** in the `$request->request->get('data')`. You fetch entity by that ID and pass the entity to `createForm()`

Comment: Yes but the thing is that I have multiple ids (multiple records to update through a single form)

Comment: @Marc I've added an untested (don't have time now) example, check it, maybe it will make my idea clear to you :)

Comment: My problem is more on how to create the form rather than how to persist the data

Comment: @Marc I'm not sure what you don't understand so I've updated the example with more details and comments. I hope it will be clear to you